# @id/profileListView is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout >>(but not itself!)

Tags: java, android-studio-2.2

am getting 2 error like this in android studio, since i can build and run the app under debug mode i cant generate a signed apk!

Error: @id/profileListView is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout [NotSibling]

this is the code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
tools:context="com.citsleb.market.ProfileFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profileContainer" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profileContentScreen"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/profileListView"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:divider="@color/listViewDivider"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:background="@color/listViewDivider">
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profileDisabledScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileDisabledScreenContent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_account_disabled"
            android:id="@+id/profileDisabledScreenMsg"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profileErrorScreen"
    android:longClickable="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/error_data_loading"
        android:id="@+id/profileErrorScreenMsg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profileLoadingScreen">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileLoadingScreenProgressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/profileListView"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorRipple" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i just solved it by adding this to buil.gradle

```
  lintOptions {
         checkReleaseBuilds false
         abortOnError false
```

Is there any problem with this?
Thanks